# Using JSON file encryption and decryption in node.js and android

Tags: android, json, node.js, encryption, cryptography

here i need to encrypt/decrypt JSON file in node.js and android using crypto library.

after some google search i only get string enc/dec but i have to do enc/dec entire json document amongst android and node.js.

any examples to achieve it in android ?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Questions should contain questions.  Asking for a library to accomplish a task is "off topic" here on StackOverflow.

Comment: what here am asking is conventional methods to accomplish those things(in android and node.js crypto library get used and i did the usual password encryption). here i don't know how to achieve it by using crypto for entire json file

Comment: Then, please use the edit button to edit your question and turn it into a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got transformable stream using pipe concept in node.js and cipherI/O stream in android.Thank you all